# Should I use Qlikview or NODE.js to represent data on the fly?

Tags: node.js, qlikview

We have a fairly big project that we need to analyze data with heavy queries. I know that NODE.js is efficient. But recently our manager said that we want to use Qlikview to show live data. Is it comparable? Can we say NODE.js OR Qlikview? What technology Google, Yahoo, etc use to demonstrate live data in dashboard?

Comment: I think you can not compare them. But I would use qlikview, because it is so easy to use.

Comment: @smartmeta do you have a tutorial for step by step installation? tnx

Answer (score 1):

here are two links for free tutorials for starting to work with QlikView:

http://www.qlik.com/us/services/training/free-training
and
http://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-1986

Regards
Stefan